# Launch activity at certain time

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent, broadcast

I'm new to Android development, so I might be missing something obvious. I want to launch an `Activity` when the user's phone clock hits a specified time (similar to an alarm). However, I'm not sure how I would go about doing this as constant polling of the clock seems inefficient and a waste of resources. Do I need to capture broadcast events from the clock, or use `PendingIntents`? If someone could point out some **SDK methods/services** I should read about, it would be much appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Bear in mind that your users will attack you with lead pipes in the conservatory if you implement this. Popping up an activity out of the blue, except for incoming phone calls, is considered impolite application behavior. After all, what if the user is in the middle of doing something when your alarm goes off?

Comment: Ah, I'm not implementing this in a released app. I'm just toying around with the SDK. But I agree, it would be crazy to launch apps unexpectedly on the phone.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take a look at the docs for [android.app.AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html).

This class allows your application to schedule PendingIntents for broadcast at specific times, which sounds like exactly what you're looking for. Just schedule a PendingIntent that launches the desired application.

Be aware that when your alarm fires, the phone will be prevented from sleeping until (and only until) `onReceive()` finishes executing. If you need to keep the phone awake longer, you may need to implement your own wake lock.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. AlarmManager looks like what I need. I think I saw it before, but read over it thinking that it was literally for the Alarm system. I'll play around with this and hopefully I'll get something working :). Thanks!